# Trying to align two columns in Bootstrap 3 and I cant figure it out

Tags: css

Might be easiest if I point you here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/user-profile-widget

What I am trying to do is align these side by side so that there are two per row...

I'm just completely confused with the order of the columns...

I guess any Bootstrap expert could please chime in with a suggestion? Thanks!

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/380x500" alt="" class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                    <h4>
                        Bhaumik Patel</h4>
                    <small><cite title="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                    </i></cite></small>
                    <p>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>email@example.com
                        <br />
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">www.jquery2dotnet.com</a>
                        <br />
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>June 02, 1988</p>
                    <!-- Split button -->
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Social</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Social</span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+Jquery2dotnet/posts">Google +</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jquery2dotnet">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Github</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question, but it seems to work just fine when including two of them on the same row.

http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/M23j